# How to get Id from url of passed object and represent attributes of that object

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Can anybody help me with eloquent?
I passed `Id` from picked product in URL and now I want to represent attributes of that table product?

This is my route:
`Route::get('/{productName}', 'ProductController@productDetails');`

Controller:

```
public function productDetails(Request $request, $productName){
        return view("productDetails");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the product object and [pass it to the view](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#passing-data-to-views):

```
public function productDetails(Request $request, $productName)
{
    $product = Product::where('name', $productName)->first();
    return view('productDetails', compact('product'));
}
```

Then you can display product properties in the view:

```
{{ $product->name }}
{{ $product->price }}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!